# Seaborn: how to get labels nicely centered in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

This is the code of my plot:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
ax = sns.countplot(x='Survived', hue='Pclass', data=data, palette="pastel")
ax.set_title("Survival in terms of Pclass", fontsize=20)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f'\n{p.get_height()}', (p.get_x()+0.2, p.get_height()), ha='center', va='top', color='white', size=18)
```

This is my plot: 
[image: resulting plot]

How can I move the values inside the graph columns nicely in the middle of each column? Now, for example number 119 is slightly cut.

Comment: Not a single accepted answer, please show some appreciation to those who are helping you

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to have the text centered with respect to the patch. You already have the x-position. The width of the patch is `p.get_width()`. Just divide it by 2 and add it to the x-position to get the center.

You can add `plt.tight_layout()` to nicely fit the plot and its labels into the image. `ax.set_xticklabels(['No', 'Yes'])` sets the labels of the x-axis.

Using the Titanic dataset:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax = sns.countplot(x='survived', hue='pclass', data=data, palette="plasma")
ax.set_title("Survival in terms of Pclass", fontsize=20)
ax.set_xticklabels(['No', 'Yes'])
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f'\n{p.get_height()}',
                (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()), ha='center', va='top', color='white', size=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: the result]